# update code does not accept letters

Tags: php, sql-update

I have the following code, why the code does not accept letters, actually it does accept letters but only if the number stays on the first place.

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST"){

$size = count($_POST['datum']);

$i = 0;
while ($i < $size) {
    $datum= $_POST['datum'][$i];
    $perso_id= $_POST['perso_id'][$i];
    $schicht= $_POST['schicht'][$i];
    if ($schicht != 0) {
        $query = "UPDATE dienstplan SET schicht = '$schicht' WHERE datum = '$datum' AND perso_id='$perso_id'";
        mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query");

    }
    ++$i;
}
```

}

Comment: Please start learning about MySQLi or PDO with prepared statements/bind variables to avoid the risks of SQL Injection

Comment: Can you give an example of input and explain, what do you mean by saying: "it doesn't accept letters"?

Answer (score 0):

you should differentiate the variable in the expressions... 
change $query to

```
$query = "UPDATE dienstplan SET schicht = '".$schicht."' WHERE datum ='". $datum."' AND perso_id='".$perso_id."'";
```

try to learn [pdo](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: Can you tell me the main reason why you are suggesting that. Thanks

Comment: it is more easy to connect to different database and it has unique function and class, rather for particular database(like mysql_query()).